# Min and Max of code not finding correct numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I have a spreadsheet of information containing information on YouTube videos. I am trying to create a program that will find the average length of the videos and the shortest and longest video. I think I found the average length, but I'm unable to get the shortest and longest video.

I used a for loop to get the information from the sheet, and then I split up the information into sections. I don't think I did that wrong, since I got the right number for the average. I'm assuming it has something to do with my max and min, but I don't know what else to do.

How can I get my max and min values to find the right numbers?

```
def main():
  my_file = open('animalVideos.csv', 'r')

  list_of_lines = my_file.read().splitlines()

  sum = 0
  counter = 0

  for i in range(1, len(list_of_lines)):
    one_line = list_of_lines[i]
    line_items = one_line.split(',')
    sum += float(line_items[2])
    counter += 1
    longest = max(line_items[2])
    shortest = min(line_items[2])

  average = sum / counter 
  print(average, shortest, longest)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
  with open('animalVideos.csv', 'r') as my_file:
      lengths = [float(line.split(',')[2]) for line in my_file.read().splitlines()[1:]]     
  print(sum(lengths)/len(lengths), min(lengths), max(lengths))


main()
```

Your code is replacing the value of `shortest` and `longest` every time you go through the `for` loop.  It's much easier to collect all the lengths in a single list, and then use that list to determine the shortest and longest video

If you're going to be doing anything more complicated than this with `csv` files, you should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, it makes things much easier

Comment: I got this error "The error value is: min of empty sequence
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function."

Comment: `min of empty sequence` suggests that your file is empty, or something is stopping us from reading all these values into our list `lengths`.  What do the first few items of `my_file.read().splitlines()` actually look like?

Comment: Title,Views,Length,Rating,From,Link
Puppy vs. cat,3879266,69,4,Sanshey,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bcV-TL9mho
CATS VS DOGS,4019679,177,3,momofbeans,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEQXIDbz6Oo

Comment: I made a minor change, slicing the list to skip the first line (because `float("Length")` obviously won't work).  Try it like that.